# Planting mint rhizomes

Tags: mint

I would like to transplant Mint to a large area as ground cover by planting 2-4 inch cuttings of rhizome. Will they grow?  Each cutting would have 2-4 fibrous roots.  Thanks,  BG

Comment: What part of the world, what kind of soil, full sun or shade?  Can you add these details by editing your question?

Answer (score 3):

Considering it's a weed, it will grow almost anywhere with little to no care (unless the area gets extremely dry). I've had success growing them from runners chopped in pieces like the ones you describe.

Make sure to keep it contained or you'll be removing mint roots and runners for years to come.